# Regular normal subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, normal-subgroups

[image: Image_1]
Hi: I don't understand the proof ($G$ is a finite group). From the equality I get $\beta=\alpha^{{(x_{\beta})^g g^{-1}}}$. Unfortunately the exponent does not necessarily belong to $N$ and so I can't use the uniqueness. Any  suggestion?

Comment: What text is this from? Also, please refrain from using pictures of text. They're not user-friendly. For example, they're hard to search and, for some devices,  they don't even render.

Comment: I see that you got this from, *"The Theory of Finite Groups: An Introduction,"* by Kurzweil & Stellmacher.

Comment: Which equality are you referring to?

Comment: The equality in the proof. Letting $g^{-1}$ act on both sides of the equality you get $\beta=\alpha^{{(x_{\beta})^g g^{-1}}}$. That is all I get. Of course if the exponent in the right side belonged to $N$, then I have two elements of $N$ sending $\alpha$ to $\beta$ and hence they're equal. But then what I get is an equality that slightly differs from that in the theorem statement!

Comment: @Shaun: Yes, the text if from that book. Thanks for your reply.